# When is it necessary to keep “it” for the sentence to be complete?

Tags: sentence-structure

Why is it necessary to put “it” in the first sentence and in the second one isn’t?

1. If I have to stay late at work tonight, [it] doesn't matter because we can go out another night.
2. To stay alone at home does not matter because I am used to it.

Comment: "To stay alone at home" doesn't sound common to me. I think it would usually be "Staying alone at home". Gerunds are often preferred over infinitives when using a verb phrase as the subject of a sentence.

Comment: The claim made in the question is backwards.  The first sentence doesn't need an "it": *Whether I have to stay late at work tonight doesn't matter, because we can go out another night.* is grammatical, while *used to it* the second sentence cannot function without "it".

Answer (score 13):

Because in most contexts, a verb must have a syntactic subject, even if it is a dummy subject such as *it*, or *there*.

In your sentence 2, the whole clause "To stay alone at home" is the subject.

In 1, the initial clause is a conditional, and cannot stand as subject, so you need a dummy subject.

You could also have used a pronominal subject *that*, which would refer to the conditional clause: *it* doesn't refer, it is (here) a meaningless word to satisfy the requirements of the syntax.

Comment: The first sentence is fine without "it". Although it parses somewhat differently the meaning is preserved.

Comment: I see what you mean, @BenVoigt, but for me, I can accept a "whether" clause as subject, but not an "if" clause.

Comment: "Whether" is clearer there because it is less flexible and guides the reader more directly to the correct meaning, but "if" can function exactly the same, even though it is more flexible and might set up a garden-path cognitive trap.

Comment: Not for me, @BenVoigt. I can accept an _if_ clause as an object of _know)_ for example, but not as a subject.

Comment: @BenVoigt Also consider the comma, which would have to be removed when "if" is replaced by "whether". The comma indicates we're looking at two clauses. On the other hand, in an informal register one could omit "it" similarly to the way one can omit "it is" in the sentence, "Not a problem."

Answer (score 0):

The it is there to show what does not matter. The 'it' references what has already been stated. The sentence should have a conjunction after the comma. Had that been in place it would have been immediately apparent why the 'it' was needed

There **is** an 'it' in the second sentence, but it is at the end, and it performs the same function.

Comment: No, the _it_ does not reference anything, and no conjunction is needed. I'm not sure whether the _it_ in the second sentence references anything or not: I'm inclined to think it is also a dummy - a dummy object, because _used to_ requires an object. But I'm not sure about that bit.